# How to execute the commands on remote Host using SSH from a web based application built in Django?

Tags: python, bash, rpc, remote-access, routed-commands

I have to execute some commands on a remote Host, this host will be a "Router". I have never ever done work with RPC calls. Another big problem is that i have to execute these commands from a `Django` web based Application. Steps are following:

- User open a page and choose a command for executing
- User choose the remote host from a given list
- User click on the execute button
- In meanwhile Django will check the security Issue. It mean that it will authorize the remote Host using `SSH`
- And the required command execute on the Host and sent back a message `"Done!"`

How i should start to work on this problem?

How should i create the SSH connection from user profile page to remote host?

For the security reason i want to create a connection using the user private key. I also find some related question but didn't got the right direction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) library, it has not so difficult api. And there are [some examples](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_simple.py) bundled with library.

You can create [ssh client](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html), pass hostname, port, username, and user's key file in constructor, [create shell](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html#invoke_shell), [run](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#exec_command) your command and [read](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#recv) commands output, stdout only. You can [read stderr](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#recv_stderr) separately, or [combine](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#set_combine_stderr) it with stdout.